# Hibernate looking for column which I've marked as @Transient

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, roo

I have a JPA entity with a few fields which is running well. I now am adding a new field and have marked it `@Transient` as I donot want it to be persisted. However on running tests or deploying the app I get an error stating: `Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing column: columnName in dbname.tableName`

Why is Hibernate looking for the column in the database schema even though I've marked it to be `Transient`?

Comment: Are you sure that you use `javax.persistence.Transient`?

Comment: My bad. Had been using `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was a mistake on my part. Was using `org.springframework.data.annotation.Transient` whereas should've been using `javax.persistence.Transient`.